# Executing Node application from Scala results in 10 times slower

Tags: scala

I have a simple Node application that reads and writes a JSON file.

The following is how the Node application is executed from Scala.

```
case class ExecResult(exitValue: Int, stdout: String, stderr: String)

def execAsync(cmd: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[ExecResult] = {
  val promise = Promise[ExecResult]
  val proc = Process(cmd).run(ProcessLogger(...))
  promise.tryCompleteWith(Future(proc.exitValue()).map(c => ExecResult(c, stdout.get, stderr.get)))
  promise.future
}
```

The execution time of this takes almost 10 times more than executing directly.

What could be the cause of this slowness?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nontrivial amount of overhead in calling out to run an external process (possibly up to and including spawning a shell (e.g. bash) to run that process).

Additionally, depending on how you're measuring this, you may also be capturing the JVM's startup and warmup phase (assuming we're talking about Scala on the JVM).

Especially if the JSON file being read is small, this overhead may swamp the actual time the Node.js application is running.

I'm not going to ask why you want to run a Node.js application from within Scala, but if you want to do something like that, I'd suggest looking at graalvm which lets you run most/any Node.js application natively in the JVM, including calling into it from e.g. Scala without the overhead of spawning an external process.  Depending on the use-case, graalvm may actually be faster than the standard V8-based node implementation.

Comment: `I'd suggest looking at graalvm` yes, we are using it. For performance comparison purposes, I am implementing it this way.

Comment: To clarify, you're comparing scala calling out to an external Node process (`Process(cmd)`) with actually running the Node code within the JVM properly?

Comment: yes, as far as I understand. I did not do the implementation with GraalVM(some other team did it), but what I heard is the performance was not as good as expected so we are trying out this implementation to see if there is any performance gain.